# How does a third-order tensor behave algebraically with respect to standard linear algebra operations?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra

## How does a Hessian tensor behave algebraically?

Suppose $H_x$ is the Hessian tensor of a multivariate function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$. This is a third-order tensor and I am told one can think about it as taking two vectors $v, w\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and returning a new vector $H_x(v, w)\in\mathbb{R}^m$.

> How does $H_x$ behave algebraically?
>
> - **Linearity**: Given vectors $v_1, v_2, w_1, w_2\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and constants $a, b, c, d\in\mathbb{R}$, how does linearity work?
>   $$
>   H_x(av_1 + bv_2, cw_1 + dw_2) \overset{?}{=} acH_x(v_1, w_1) + adH_x(v_1, w_2) + bcH_x(v_2, w_1) + bdH_x(v_2, w_2)
>   $$
> - **Matrix Multiplication on $v$**: Given $A$ an $n\times n$ matrix can I "take it out"? And in this case, which side do I take it out to?
>   $$
>   H_x(Av, w) \overset{?}{=} AH_x(v, w) \quad \text{or} \quad \overset{?}{=}H_x(v, w)A \quad \text{or something else?}
>   $$
> - **Matrix Multiplication on $w$**: Given $B$ an $n\times n$ matrix multiplying $w$ can I take it out? Where does it go?
>   $$
>   H_x(v, Bw) \overset{?}{=} BH_x(v, w) \quad \text{or}\quad \overset{?}{=}H_x(v, w)B \quad \text{or something else?}
>   $$
> - **Compatibility with other operations**: In many circumstances one has $H_x$ appearing in a product, so it is natural to wonder how it behaves when it is multiplied by tensors of lower order (such as matrices and vectors).
>
>   - *Vector multiplication*: If it is multiplied on the right by a vector, does it get absorbed into one of the arguments?  $H_x y \overset{?}{=} H_x(y, \cdot)$ or $\overset{?}{=} H_x(\cdot, y)$?
>   - *Matrix multiplication*: If it is multiplied on the right or left by a matrix, does it get absorbed into one of the arguments?
>     $$
>     A H_x y B \overset{?}{=} H_x(AyB, \cdot) \quad \text{or} \overset{?}{=}A H_x(By, \cdot)
>     $$
>     How about
>     $$
>     C(AH_x B) = ?
>     $$

Comment: Notice the expressions $AH(v,w)$ and $BH(v,w)$ don't make sense. Dimesions don't match.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz My observation exactly! However in various questions people say it is linear with respect to matrix multiplication, which I suppose must be, but apart from index notation, no one shows what it means practically speaking

Comment: You seem to be confused about what sort of object $H_x$ is. If $H_x : \mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$, then the notation $H_xy$ is (a priori) nonsensical. Now, if you have a function $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, then its Hessian function $H_x : \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ has an $n{\times}n$ matrix $M_x$ such that $H_x(v, w) = v^TM_xw$. If we conflate $H_x$ with $M_x$, then what we mean by $H_xw$ is $M_xw$, and the function $v \mapsto v^TM_xw$ is $H_x(\cdot, w)$; so in this sense $M_xw$ represents $H_x(\cdot, w)$.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff that's all very true, but the problem is that I am working with $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$. I am familiar with a Hessian matrix but I don't understand how does a Hessian tensor behave algebraically.

Comment: @Euler_Salter it means nothing because it makes no sense as is. If you could edit your question to include references to the "various questions [where] people mention it is linear with respect to matrix multiplication", together with your observations about those statements, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

$$H_x(v, w) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t_1}\frac{\partial}{\partial t_2}(f(x + t_1v + t_2w))|_{t_1 = 0}|_{t_2 = 0} = \sum_{j, k = 1}^{n}f_{x_j x_k}v^j w^k.$$
Hence $$(H_x(v, w))_i = H_{f_i}(x)(v, w) = (v, H_{f_i}(x)w).$$
In general, $(Ax, y) = (x, A^Ty)$ for vectors $x, y$ and matrix $A$.